# Create Managed Object in the block from json?

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa

My app crashes when i create managed object from json in the block

```
NSManagedObject *tempObject;
NSManagedObjectContext *temporaryContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[temporaryContext setParentContext:delegate.mainManagedObjectContext];

for (NSDictionary* objd in objects) {
    tempObject = targetParser(objd, temporaryContext);
    [objectsArray addObject:tempObject];
}

mutableResult[@"objects"] = [objectsArray copy];

return [mutableResult copy];
return mutableResult;
```

---

```
const static id (^routesDeserializer)(NSDictionary*, NSManagedObjectContext*) = ^id (NSDictionary* d, NSManagedObjectContext* context) {

Route* r = [Route newObjectWithContext:context];
r.identifier = d[resourceIdKey];
r.name = d[resourceNameKey];
r.sequenceDescription = d[routeDescriptionKey];
r.capacityType = d[routeCapacityTypeKey];
r.objectHash = d[resourceHashKey];
r.city = d[resourceCityIdKey];
r.checkpoint = d[routeCheckpointIdsKey];

return r;
};
```

What i'm doing wrong? Does it right if i use temporaryContext in the block? Because this is split to different threads(i think).

p.s. i'm newbie to objective c and i'm from russia, so excuse me for my english

---

sorry, forget about log

```
2015-11-25 11:16:57.610 TTCore Light[1331:65573] -[__NSCFNumber    managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a95fe10
2015-11-25 11:16:57.637 TTCore Light[1331:65573] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a95fe10'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00e7da84 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x005a1e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00e86dd3 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00dc4cdd ___forwarding___ + 1037
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00dc48ae _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   CoreData                            0x009f9061 _PFManagedObject_coerceValueForKeyWithDescription + 337
6   CoreData                            0x009cd0ad _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 205
7   CoreData                            0x009cdef7 _svfk_8 + 39
8   TTCore Light                        0x000cc34d routesDeserializer_block_invoke + 669
9   TTCore Light                        0x000cddb8 +[UpdateController deserializeObjectsFromJson:withObjectsType:andContext:] + 1368
10  TTCore Light                        0x000cea71 __52-[UpdateController connectionForType:initialUpdate:]_block_invoke + 897
11  CFNetwork                           0x02cb5e37 __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 48
12  CFNetwork                           0x02cca0a7 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 353
13  Foundation                          0x0024ea6b __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
14  Foundation                          0x001728ff -[NSBlockOperation main] + 108
15  Foundation                          0x00152d84 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 697
16  Foundation                          0x00152ac4 -[NSOperation start] + 83
17  Foundation                          0x00152902 __NSOQSchedule_f + 245
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x034af9cd _dispatch_client_callout + 14
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03493650 _dispatch_queue_drain + 2227
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03492b04 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 570
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x034957bb _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 550
22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0349558e _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 115
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x037cf270 _pthread_wqthread + 1050
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x037ccf82 start_wqthread + 34
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: What are the details of the crash?

Comment: Sorry if im wrong, but my guess is that its not really related to block, but your object must be implements `NSCoding` protocol, did u have it?

Comment: No, i don't have nscoding, can you show me example?